# UI Router cannot $state.go to sub state and show named view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I tried to follow [the document](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) to create a named view for my sub state and $state.go to it from it's parent state, but it is unsuccessful. [Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k1mjq5T2Be3nrlGDJdu6?p=preview) for your editing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script>
      let app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.router']);
    
      app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($up, $sp) {
        $sp.state('state1', state1);
        $sp.state('state1.state2', state2);
        $up.otherwise('/state1');
      }]);
      
      let state1 = {
        url: '/state1',
        controller: ['$state', function ($st) {
          this.stName = $st.current.name;
          this.createSubState = function(){
            $st.go('state1.state2', {message: 'message from ' + $st.current.name + ' to state2'});
          }
        }],
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: `<div style="border-style: solid;">
          <p ng-click="$ctrl.createSubState()" style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">{{$ctrl.stName}} begin</p>
          <ui-view="stat2View"></ui-view>
          <p>{{$ctrl.stName}} end</p>
        </div>`
      };
      
      let state2 = {
        params: {
          message: ''
        },
        views: {
          stat2View: {
            controller: ['$transition$', '$state', function ($tr, $st) {
              this.parentMessage = $tr.params().message;
              this.stName = $st.current.name;
            }],
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            template: `<div style="border-style: solid;">
              <p style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">{{$ctrl.stName}} begin</p>
              {{$ctrl.parentMessage}}
              <p>{{$ctrl.stName}} end</p>
            </div>`
          }
        }
      };

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to do this is because I'm using dynamic generated states to show left-side nav-panel against a navTreeModal fetched from the server, so I have to give names to views or they mess up.

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where almost there: [corrected plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9vjqvtRTtwX24Si160CW?p=preview)

What I did:

- The `ui-view="state2View"` has to be `ui-view name="state2View"`
- The views name property `stat2View` has to be `"stat2View@state1"`, because it refers to a parent states ui-view

**EDIT**

Either use the ui-view declaration like:

```
<ui-view name="viewsName" />
```

or

```
<div ui-view="viewsName"></div>
```

Comment: You are grate! Thank you for help me again! According to the document relative name should be OK so I still confused on the name why it has to be absolute by using '@'.

Comment: It's a pleasure :) When you start using views, you have to assign to what view (in what state this view is originally rendered) you want to put your controller/component. In the docs, the last code block explains it actual good: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

Comment: I tested again, using short/relative names for views is just fine;)

Comment: Oh ok, wrote that down :)